# Etmyology of "ombo"

Tags: meaning, etymology

I got "ombo" rides from my Grandfather. What is the etymology of "ombo" which does not appear in standard dictionaries?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 負んぶ? http://jisho.org/word/%E8%B2%A0%E3%82%93%E3%81%B6

Answer (score 8):

The *ombo* word you remember is almost certainly from Japanese 負{お}んぶ (*ombu*: "to carry piggyback").  This comes from older 負{お}ぶう (*obuu*), which in turn appears to be the continuous / repetitive form of classical 負{お}ふ (*ofu*, ancient *opu* "to put on one's back"; modern form 負{お}う, *ou*).

Comment: Thanks   http://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5229/eir%c3%adkr-%c3%9atlend1 Probably I mispronounced "ombu" as "ombo"